# Javascript with images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am currently trying to insert image with Javascript attached to it and for some reason it works on Firefox but the images or icons do not display on IE.

I have done the coding like this:

```
<a href="javascript:changesize('xxx')">
    <img src="Images/changesize.jpg" title="Change Text Size">
</a>

<a href="javascript:changefont('xxx')">
    <img src="Images/changefont.jpg" title="Change Font">
</a>

<a href="javascript:changeline('xxx')">
    <img src="Images/changeline.jpg" title="Change Line Spacing">
</a>

<a href="javascript:changecolors('xxx')">
    <img src="Images/changecolors.jpg" title="Change Text/Backgroud Colors">
</a>
```

Comment: Please show your javascript and explain what you are wanting to achieve

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't post your code?

Comment: basically i have 4 icons which calls of a java script.  The four java script is for controlling contrast, changing text font, adjusting line spacing.  the problem that am having is that the script works fine but the icons are not showing up on ie explorer it just shows an x however works on morzilla

Comment: That x means it can not access the files usually. Can you look at the server access files for example to see what URL it tries to load?

Comment: Try adding `./` to the img src: `./Images/###.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
<img src="Images/changeline.jpg" title="Change Line Spacing" onclick="changeline('xxx')">
```

Comment: still the same problem i just get an x on ie explorer

Comment: You need to fix `onclick` it need quotes. Remove the spaces